# What happens within the convergence of two event horizons?

Tags: black-holes, event-horizon

What would happen if someone stood between two equally massive black holes, so that every particle of their body was contained in the region of both event horizons? Would they be:
a) Totally immobilized
b) Unaffected by any forces, ie the black holes would cancel each other out, or
c) Ripped apart?

Comment: The situation you describe is impossible. You could not maintain two black holes with their event horizons in contact.

Comment: What would happen? Would they combine into one black hole, or stretch each other back into sub-black matter?

Comment: The only way to maintain a constant distance between two black holes is to make them orbit each other - after all, you can't hold onto a black hole. However when the spacing between the horizons is less than a few times the event horizon radius the orbit becomes unstable and the black holes spiral in and merge. The point is that your question is meaningless because it relies on a situation that isn't physically possible.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is based on an impossible premise.

Comment: @HDE226868 What's impossible about the premise? The physics is wrong in that "two event horizons" is meaningless, but that seems to be an innocent mis-wording by a non-expert. The criticism in the earlier comments are not rooted in what the OP actually asked, i.e. he didn't say anything about keeping black holes at constant distance. Falling directly into each other is a theoretically valid scenario for understanding a two black hole space time that is consistent with the wording of the question. Wanting to understand something at the symmetry point between them seems valid.

Answer (score 2):

Contrary to the comments on the original question, I think the physical situation is theoretically possible.  The comments are correct that the black holes cannot maintain a constant distance, but under the scenario described, they will fall directly toward each other and the observer who started half way in between will maintain a symmetric relationship to the two black holes (albeit a time-varying relationship to them).  The OP doesn't state that the distance between the black holes must be constant, just that the observer starts half way between them.

Given that situation, the person, having finite size, will eventually be torn in half.  Any point particle directly at the half-way point will theoretically be held in an unstable equilibrium until the two black holes ultimately collide at that point.

Now the OP is wrong insofar as he talks about being inside two event horizons.  There will be only one event horizon in this system, since an event horizon by definition is a global property of the spacetime, and these black holes will merge.  I think that's a detail that's beyond the scope of what the OP really wanted to know though.

Comment: Q: Event horizon is a property of "the system?" or a property of some observer's _relationship_ to the system?  (i.e., I can't see you because you have passed beyond _my_ event horizon.)

Comment: @jameslarge The event horizon does not depend on the observer. It is a property of the spacetime as a whole.